# Mule ESB SFTP connecter dynamic input Path

Tags: mule

I want to give the input path from database in mule  S FTP INBOUND Connector where it will pick up file according to database Path.
But I am unable to solve this issue ;
Is this possible or not...?
Anybody can you please answer on this ?
please.

Answer (score 2):

Use a poll component in mule.
Inside the poll component add a Java Component.
And make the Java class implements Callable.

In the OnCall method make a custom Endpoint like this :

```
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
EndpointBuilder endpointBuilder = muleEventContext
                .getMuleContext()
                .getEndpointFactory()
                .getEndpointBuilder(
                        protocol+"://" + username + ":"
                                + password+ "@"
                                + host + ":"+port
                                + path );
    InboundEndpoint inboundEndPoint = endpointBuilder
                .buildInboundEndpoint();
```

Now these user name and password you can fetch from DB.
Either put a REST layer on top of DB and expose Webservices to fetch Data and using an HTTP client fetch the data and dynamically populate username,password,host and path.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use MEL to define which path your SFTP is going to use. Yet you can load the path from a properties file as follows. HTH.

```
<sftp:endpoint name="SFTP-Endpoint"
    connector-ref="SFTP" host="${sftp.host}" user="${sftp.user}"
    password="${sftp.jdeBillingReportPassword}" port="${sftp.port}"
    path="${sftp.path}" />
```

Comment: This is not the answer.....!                                                                           Sir I know this but I want to pick the file according to database path..!

Comment: You can use the requester module after the database path. That way you can get the file in the middle of the flow. For more info about this check: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/introducing-the-mule-requester-module/ . HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible by writing a groovy script.
In the groovy script you can reference a flowVar(ex: imageRef) that will have the path of the file to retrieve:

```
    <scripting:component doc:name="Script"> 
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy">
            <![CDATA[def ftpFileUri = "ftp://${ftp.username}:${ftp.password}@${ftp.host}/${ftp.path}" + message.getInvocationProperty('imageRef') + ".jpg";
            muleContext.client.request(ftpFileUri, 30000L);]]>
        </scripting:script>  
    </scripting:component>
```

In your case, prior to this you would just need to query the database and store the value in your flowVar.

also if the file does not exist, you can catch the groovy exception in a "an exception strategy" and log it with:

`<logger message="#[groovy:message.getExceptionPayload().getRootException().getMessage()]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Logger"></logger>`

Comment: Sir can you please explain ...!                                                                                        I want to take the sftp input path from Database...!

Comment: Sure, add a database component in your flow with the right query to get your path. Once you get that, you can use the groovy script I posted above to retrieve an ftp file.

Comment: sir but I can not used database component before SFTP because if I can do like this then mule is not able to pick the file because SFTP become OUTBOUND SFTP. So Can you please say me what can I do now

Comment: Just dont use the SFTP component, just put a groovy block and then paste the script I talk about above. You will need to adapt it to your needs.